# Greendao tree entity implementation: parent and children from the same entity, doesn't compile

Tags: tree, entity, greendao

I need some advice on making a tree representation with an entity defined with the ORM GREENDAO.

In fact, I can't generate the dao files with my reflexive properties.
I tried to implement a simple tree of CATEGORIES.

The category 1 can have a category 0 as a parent and the category 1 can also have several categories as children. So two foreign keys pointing to the same entity category as the source and target.

I tried the code that greendao propose on their site to make a tree entity, see [Section "Modelling Tree Relations (Example)" on the page](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/).

My problematic code:

```
Entity categories = schema.addEntity("CATEGORIES");
categories.addIdProperty().primaryKey();
Property parentId= categories.addLongProperty("parentId").notNull().getProperty();
ToOne ParentCat = categories.addToOne(categories, parentId);
ParentCat.setName("parentId");
Property childrenId= categories.addLongProperty("childrenId").notNull().getProperty();
ToMany ChildrenCat = categories.addToMany(categories, childrenId);
ChildrenCat.setName("children");
```

And I've got theses exceptions from compiler:

```
greenDAO Generator
Copyright 2011-2015 Markus Junginger, greenrobot.de. Licensed under GPL V3.
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Currently only single FK columns are supported: ToOne 'parentId' from CATEGORIES to CATEGORIES
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.ToOne.init3ndPass(ToOne.java:91)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Entity.init3rdPassRelations(Entity.java:603)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Entity.init3rdPass(Entity.java:596)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Schema.init3rdPass(Schema.java:185)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.generateAll(DaoGenerator.java:91)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.generateAll(DaoGenerator.java:79)
    at Apptree_DAO_Generator.main(Apptree_DAO_Generator.java:13)*
```

or

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Source properties do not match target properties: ToMany 'children' from CATEGORIES to CATEGORIES
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.ToMany.init2ndPass(ToMany.java:59)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Entity.init2ndPass(Entity.java:517)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Schema.init2ndPass(Schema.java:179)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.generateAll(DaoGenerator.java:90)
    at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.generateAll(DaoGenerator.java:79)
    at Apptree_DAO_Generator.main(Apptree_DAO_Generator.java:13)*
```

So, a foreign key from and to the same entity table seems problematic.
Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you need a single bidirectional 1-to-n relation. Try something like this:

```
Entity categories = schema.addEntity("CATEGORIES");
categories.addIdProperty().primaryKey();
Property parentId= categories.addLongProperty("parentId").notNull().getProperty();
ToOne ParentCat = categories.addToOne(categories, parentId);
ParentCat.setName("parent");
ToMany ChildrenCat = categories.addToMany(categories, parentId);
ChildrenCat.setName("children");
```

After that, you have to set the parent for each category

```
categoryB.setParent(categoryA);
categoryC.setParent(categoryB);
categoryD.setParent(categoryB);
```

When you need to use the relations, using `categoryB` you will get `categoryA` by calling `categoryB.getParent()`. And the same goes for the children, you will get a list with `categoryC` and `categoryD` when you call `categoryB.getChildren()`

Comment: Thanks man, it's been a while for now... Finally I drop Greendao and use ActiveAndroid instead... Thanks for your help anyway